# javascript google chrome extension getting domain name

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

I tried to get the domain name using `alert(document.domain);` But i'm not getting the right domain when I test it out in a site,

I get "hiecjmnbaldlmopbbkifcelmaaalcfib" this weird output.

I have added this in the manifest too

```
  "content_scripts": [
        {
        "js": ["inject.js"]

        }
  ],
```

alert(document.domain); is the only line of text inside inject.js.

And I've incorporated this `<script type="text/javascript" src="inject.js">
    </script>` into the main html file after `popup.js`

Any thoughts on why I'm not getting the correct domain url?

Thanks!

Comment: what about `window.top.location`?

Comment: The 'weird' output is the id of your app, what domain value are you expecting?

Comment: @lostsource stackoverflow, latimes, yahoo, etc... all sorts of domain names

Comment: @EliranMalka for some reason `window.top.location` keeps outputting `chrome-extension://(the app id)/popup.html`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are in popup or background or options page, there is an indirect approach for obtaining domain of page.

You can refer to following code as a reference.

## Demonstration

#### manifest.json

Registered content scripts, background and popup scripts with manifest file along with relevant permissions

```
{
    "name": "Domain Name",
    "description": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796722/javascript-google-chrome-extension-getting-domain-name",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "myscript.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

#### myscript.js

```
console.log(document.domain);// Outputs present active URL of tab
```

#### popup.html

Registered `popup.js` to surpass CSP.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body></body>

</html>
```

#### popup.js

Added Event Listener for `DOM Content Loaded`, and brought active URL of tab where user is on.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    console.log(document.domain);//It outputs id of extension to console
    chrome.tabs.query({ //This method output active URL 
        "active": true,
        "currentWindow": true,
        "status": "complete",
        "windowType": "normal"
    }, function (tabs) {
        for (tab in tabs) {
            console.log(tabs[tab].url);
        }
    });
});
```

#### background.js

```
console.log(document.domain); //It outputs id of extension to console
chrome.tabs.query({ //This method output active URL 
    "active": true,
    "currentWindow": true,
    "status": "complete",
    "windowType": "normal"
}, function (tabs) {
    for (tab in tabs) {
        console.log(tabs[tab].url);
    }
});
```

## Output

You will find

> fgbhocadghoeonlokakijhnlplgkolbg

as output for console.log(document.domain); in all extension pages and

and

> http://somedomain.com/

for `tabs.query()` output.

However, Content script output is always

> http://somedomain.com/

## References

- [Tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query)
- [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)

Comment: Wow this helped a lot! Can you explain what is the need for background.js?

Comment: @andrewliu: I have just shown an alternate approach using **`background.js`**, this is for your reference..